# 118:51: Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return

Tags: reactjs

everything is working fine but i am getting this error  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return can you help me with this

```
<div className="websites-caraousel">
                  <div className={`left-arrow ${0 !== lowerLimit && 'activated'}`} onClick = {moveLeft} >
                    <img src={LeftIcon}   width="64px" alt=""/>
                  </div>

                {allWebsitesData.map((item,index) => {
                    console.log(item)
                  if (index >=  lowerLimit && index <= upperLimit && item.name.includes(searchString))
                  {  console.log(item,"passed")
                      return <div className="website-grid">
                        <div className={`website-grid-hero ${item.type}-thumbnail`}></div>
                        <span>{item.name}</span>
                        <Button variant="contained" onClick = {function(e) { getDetails(e,item.name); } } color="primary">Details</Button>
                      </div>
                    }
                })}


                  <div className={`right-arrow ${allWebsitesData.length-1 !== upperLimit && 'activated'}`} onClick = {moveRight}>
                    <img src={RightIcon} width="64px" alt=""/>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: can you edit your post and add the error messaging in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it states, it expects you to return a value. The culprit is your call to `allWebsitesData.map`.

You're returning inside the if, but you don't have a fallback outside of it. Simply return `null` or precede your call to `.map` with one to `.filter` so you don't need the `if` in the first place.

Something like:

```
{allWebsitesData
    .filter((item,index) => index >= lowerLimit && index <= upperLimit && item.name.includes(searchString))
    .map(item => (
        <div className="website-grid">
            <div className={`website-grid-hero ${item.type}-thumbnail`}></div>
            <span>{item.name}</span>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick = {function(e) { getDetails(e,item.name); } } color="primary">Details</Button>
         </div>
    ))}
```

Comment: I like the filter approach, why don't you add an example for Yash to follow?

Comment: @LuisSardon Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on your map, you are not returning anything after the "if" validation, try returning null:

```js
{allWebsitesData.map((item,index) => {
  ...
  if (...) {
    ...
  }
  
  return null;
})}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an if condition inside a map. In case the condition is true, then it will return the new div with "website-grid" className, but what happens if not? it doesn't return anything.

The map method will always return a new array with the same length the array you're mapping through. You should do the filtering in another method or add a `filter` before, then map the result to return the divs.

```
{filteredAllWebsitesData().map((item, index) => (
  <div className="website-grid">
    <div className={`website-grid-hero ${item.type}-thumbnail`}></div>
    <span>{item.name}</span>
    <Button
       variant="contained" 
       onClick = {function(e) { getDetails(e,item.name); } } 
       color="primary"
    >
      Details
    </Button>
  </div>
)}
```